# How can I improve adding/removing items to an array code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a list of items, I want to remove or add an item from `myStock`if it is selected or deselected. The problem I am having is once an item is selected the browser crushes. Is the a way I can do this better?

**HTML:**

```
  <ion-list>
            <div *ngFor="let item of stockList | speciesSearchPipe:listFilter.value">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        {{ item.name_eng }}
                        <img src="./assets/images/species_icons/{{item.image_file}}" width="60" style="float: right;"/>
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-checkbox class="item-avatar item-checkbox-right" color="dark" checked="false" (click)="selectSpecie(item)"></ion-checkbox>
                </ion-item>
            </div>
  </ion-list>
```

**TS:**

```
let myStock = this.apiService.currentUser.data.coop.jdata;
        if (myStock) {
            for (let x = 0; myStock.stocklist.length > x; x++) {
                myStock.stocklist["fish_species_id"] === item.fish_species_id ? myStock.stocklist.splice(x,1) : myStock.stocklist.push(item);
            };
        } else {
            myStock = {};
            myStock["stocklist"] = [];
            myStock.stocklist.push(item);
        };

        console.log(myStock); // First log is as expected, then the app freezes
```

Comment: What is `jdata`?

Comment: Where is the function `selectSpecie(item)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `for`-loop with this:

```
let index = myStock.stocklist.indexOf(item);
if(index >= 0) {
    myStock.stocklist.splice(index, 1);
} else {
    myStock.stocklist.push(item);
}
```

Full code:

```
let myStock = this.apiService.currentUser.data.coop.jdata;
if (myStock) {
    let index = myStock.stocklist.indexOf(item);
    if (index >= 0) {
        myStock.stocklist.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        myStock.stocklist.push(item);
    }
} else {
    myStock = {};
    myStock["stocklist"] = [];
    myStock.stocklist.push(item);
};

console.log(myStock);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!myStock) {
  myStock = { 
    stockList: [item]
  };
} else {
  const index = myStock.stockList.findIndex(({item.fish_species_id}) => item.fish_species_id === item.fish_species_id);
  if(index !== -1) {
    myStock.stockList[index] = item;
  } else {
    myStock.stockList.push(item);
  }
}
console.log(myStock);
```